# React Native: createMaterialTopTabNavigator align current Tab during swipe with scrollable

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have problem with my scrollable materialTopTabNavigator stuff. When I swipe to another tab, I see delay, but then the selected tab aligns. My behavior in the first gif.
https://ibb.co/yXsCbFh

I need behavior like this, without delay and with auto align
https://ibb.co/c67BSQf

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar performance issues and am able to workaround them by disabling Remote JS Debugging.
or

Without spending much time into the issue, you might want to check debug > slow animations in your ios simulator.